Microsoft Graph API Calendar Event is found but can't be deleted
I built a calendar syncer which works kinda fine.
Sometimes it has issues and just can't delete an event.
Note: All the events have been created with the API and the same credentials
The odd thing is, that I query the event before I delete it.
Here is a simple code to reproduce the issue:
async def delete_all_future_events(calendar_id, dry_run=True):
    # Scopes required for accessing and modifying calendar events
    scopes = ['https://graph.microsoft.com/.default']

    tenant_id = ''
    client_id = ''
    client_secret = ''
    user_id = ''

    # Initialize ClientSecretCredential
    credential = ClientSecretCredential(
        tenant_id=tenant_id,
        client_id=client_id,
        client_secret=client_secret
    )

    # Create GraphServiceClient
    graph_client = GraphServiceClient(credential, scopes)

    # Define date range for fetching events
    start_date = datetime.now(pytz.utc)
    end_date = start_date + timedelta(days=365)

    # Format dates correctly for the Graph API in ISO 8601 format
    start_date_str = start_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z")
    end_date_str = end_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z")
    
    # Adjust timezone offset formatting
    start_date_str = start_date_str[:-2] + ":" + start_date_str[-2:]
    end_date_str = end_date_str[:-2] + ":" + end_date_str[-2:]

    # Set up request configuration with date range
    query_params = CalendarViewRequestBuilder.CalendarViewRequestBuilderGetQueryParameters(
        start_date_time=start_date_str,
        end_date_time=end_date_str,
        select=['id', 'subject', 'start', 'end'],
        top=100,
        orderby=['start/dateTime ASC']
    )

    headers = HeadersCollection()
    headers.add("Prefer", 'outlook.timezone="Europe/Berlin"')

    request_configuration = RequestConfiguration(
        query_parameters=query_params,
        headers=headers
    )

    try:
        # Fetch all events within the next year
        events_page = await graph_client.users.by_user_id(user_id).calendars.by_calendar_id(calendar_id).calendar_view.get(request_configuration=request_configuration)
        total_deleted = 0
        
        while True:
            if hasattr(events_page, 'value') and events_page.value:
                for event in events_page.value:
                    event_type = event.subject.split("-")[0]
                    if event_type != "Feiertag":
                        event_id = event.id
                        event_subject = event.subject
                        print(f"Attempting to delete event: {event_subject} (ID: {event_id})")
                        
                        # Call delete function with dry_run option
                        delete_result = await delete_calendar_event(calendar_id, event_id, dry_run=dry_run)
                        if delete_result:
                            total_deleted += 1
                            print(f"Deleted event: {event_subject} (ID: {event_id})")
                        else:
                            print(f"Failed to delete event: {event_subject} (ID: {event_id})")
            
            if not events_page.odata_next_link:
                print("No more pages to fetch.")
                break

            # Fetch the next page of events if available
            events_page = await graph_client.users.by_user_id(user_id).calendars.by_calendar_id(calendar_id).events.with_url(events_page.odata_next_link).get()

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error deleting events: {e}")

    print(f"Total events deleted: {total_deleted if not dry_run else 0}")

asyncio.run(delete_all_future_events(calendar_id, dry_run=False))

The error is the following
Error deleting event: 
        APIError
        Code: 404
        message: None
        error: MainError(additional_data={}, code='ErrorItemNotFound', details=None, inner_error=None, message='The specified object was not found in the store.', target=None)

EDIT: I also cannot delete them via the outlook UI anymore

Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70877927/delete-calendar-event-permanently-using-microsoft-graph-api

@Rukmini not sure what I should get from there.

Can you also include the API by which you created event?

basically await client.users.by_user_id(USER_ID).calendars.by_calendar_id(calendar_id).events.post(body=event)
where client is def get_graph_client():     """Initialize and return Microsoft Graph client."""     credential = ClientSecretCredential(TENANT_ID, CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET)     scopes = ['https://graph.microsoft.com/.default']     return GraphServiceClient(credential, scopes)

To fetch and delete calendar events, I modified the code like below:
tenant_id = 'TenantID'
client_id = 'ClientID'
client_secret = 'Secret'
scopes = ['https://graph.microsoft.com/.default']

credentials = ClientSecretCredential(tenant_id, client_id, client_secret)
graph_client = GraphServiceClient(credentials, scopes)

async def delete_calendar_event(calendar_id, event_id):
    try:
        await graph_client.users.by_user_id('UserID').calendars.by_calendar_id(calendar_id).events.by_event_id(event_id).delete()
        return True
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error deleting event ID {event_id}: {e}")
        return False

async def get_calendar_view():
    query_params = CalendarViewRequestBuilder.CalendarViewRequestBuilderGetQueryParameters(
        start_date_time="2023-10-09T00:00:00Z",
        end_date_time="2025-11-09T12:27:39Z",
    )

    request_configuration = RequestConfiguration(
        query_parameters=query_params,
    )

    calendar_id = 'CalendarID'
    result = await graph_client.users.by_user_id('UserID').calendars.by_calendar_id(calendar_id).calendar_view.get(request_configuration=request_configuration)

    if hasattr(result, 'value') and result.value:
        for event in result.value:
            event_type = event.subject.split("-")[0]
            if event_type != "Feiertag":
                event_id = event.id
                event_subject = event.subject
                print(f"Attempting to delete event: {event_subject} (ID: {event_id})")

                # Call delete function
                delete_result = await delete_calendar_event(calendar_id, event_id)
                if delete_result:
                    print(f"Deleted event: {event_subject} (ID: {event_id})")
                else:
                    print(f"Failed to delete event: {event_subject} (ID: {event_id})")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(get_calendar_view())



        APIError
        Code: 404
        message: None
        error: MainError(additional_data={}, code='ErrorItemNotFound', details=None, inner_error=None, message='The specified object was not found in the store.', target=None)``` 

Even tho I am querying it like I mentioned before.

Did you try my code?

Yes, this is the output I pasted for you.

Can you try doing it in Microsoft Graph Api ?

What exactly? Deleting something? Please link a source or whatever so I'd love to try.

Can you try calling  the API here https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer
